# Roundcube: How do decrease response time to failed login attempts?

Tags: roundcube

I'm tweaking my roundcube configuration which is using postfix/dovecot on the backend.

One annoyance is that if bad credentials are provided, it takes roundcube 20 to 30 seconds to respond. I was able to get this down to a more reasonable 8 seconds by setting `$config['imap_timeout'] = 1` but that's still pretty slow.

Judging by the logs, roundcube tries to login 5 or 6 times before giving up. Is there a way to change how many times it logs in? Is there another way to improve response time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this hack: https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/issues/7754

Change line 163 of the `rcube_imap.php` file in Debian distribution of rc in `/var/lib/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube` to:

`} while(!$this->conn->connected() && $data['retry']);`